# python get list from one class to another

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to get the test_list back to the first class. How can I do that if i want to use the self.pushbutton.clicked.connect(self.xy)
thanks

```
class test(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
       self.test.setupUi(self) # QT
       #do something
       self.pushbutton.clicked.connect(self.connect1)

    def connect1(self):
        window = other_window(self)
        otherview.show()

    def need_list(self):
        print(test_list)

class other_window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow)
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.other_window.setupUi(self) # QT
        #do something
        self.pushbutton.clicked.connect(self.connect2)

    def connect2(self):
        # do something
        self.pushbutton.clicked.connect(self.return_list)

    def return_list(self):
        test_list = []
        test_list.append("a", "b", "c")
        # return test_list to need_list
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make `test_list` a global variable. By that I mean you should declare it before both classes and access them in the classes. Example:

```py
test_list = []
class test(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    ...
```

and then in return list:

```py
def return_list(self):
    global test_list
    # do what you want with it
```

Once you do this, `need_list` can access `test_list`. Look [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-local-variables-python/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `test_list`, a variable created by a method of `other_window`, from an instance of `test`, you have a couple options.

Assuming you've defined an instance of `test` globally somewhere, you can call `need_list()` and give `test_list` as an argument. For example:

```
class test(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
       self.test.setupUi(self) # QT
       #do something
       self.pushbutton.clicked.connect(self.connect1)

    def connect1(self):
        window = other_window(self)
        otherview.show()

    def need_list(self, test_list):
        print(test_list)

class other_window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow)
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.other_window.setupUi(self) # QT
        #do something
        self.pushbutton.clicked.connect(self.connect2)

    def connect2(self):
        # do something
        self.pushbutton.clicked.connect(self.return_list)

    def return_list(self):
        test_list = []
        test_list.append("a", "b", "c")
        return test_list

test_instance = test()  # Or however you defined these
other_window_instance = other_window()

test_instance.need_list(other_window_instance.return_list())
```

You could also make `test_list` global. This would require less change at the cost of some flexibility:

```
class test(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
       self.test.setupUi(self) # QT
       #do something
       self.pushbutton.clicked.connect(self.connect1)

    def connect1(self):
        window = other_window(self)
        otherview.show()

    def need_list(self):
        print(test_list)

class other_window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow)
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.other_window.setupUi(self) # QT
        #do something
        self.pushbutton.clicked.connect(self.connect2)

    def connect2(self):
        # do something
        self.pushbutton.clicked.connect(self.return_list)

    def return_list(self):
        global test_list

        test_list = []
        test_list.append("a", "b", "c")

test_instance = test()
other_window_instance = other_window()
```

Python has variable scopes (see [the Python documentation on execution](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/executionmodel.html)), meaning that in your original program, `need_list()` is unable to see `test_list` because it is defined locally. Anything outside that function is unable to see `test_list` unless you declare it a global variable (with the `global` keyword used in the second option, which allows it to be seen anywhere except in the bodies of functions that reassign to the same name. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/unboundlocalerror-on-local-variable-when-reassigned-after-first-use) for more about this) or pass it to a function explicitly (using a function argument in `need_list()` as demonstrated in the first option).

Hope this helped!

Comment: It should be noted that the full repost of the original code is not a good idea, and that's due to the fact that the second slot connection won't do anything at all. I'd suggest you to edit the post so that it reports that. I'd also add the suggestion to avoid connecting to a signal whenever the connection is created from the same signal too (or, at least, ensure that the signal is connected only once): if the button is clicked multiple times, that would result in the second signal being called once more each time.

Comment: I thought about removing the unchanged code, but I wasn't sure exactly what parts to keep. I think you have the reputation to edit my post for me, since you seem to know what to do better than I do.

Comment: I really don't like to edit people's answers (and, most importantly, their code) unless I believe it's really necessary, since I'm afraid it could change the original intent and sense of the answer, and also because I think that self-editing offers lots of insights. I'll leave your answer as it is, as I think that my comment might be enough for future readers to offer more information (that's what comments are for), and, if someday you'll remember it and find the time to edit it, it will mean that somebody else (you, specifically, but not only) will get some more benefit from it :-)